# Apply styles to a class with consecutive numbers

Tags: css, css-selectors

.item-0, .item-1, .item-2, .item-3, .item-4, .item-5, .item-6, .item-7, .item-8, .item-9, .item-10, .item-11, .item12 {
   padding: 0 10px;
}

to:

.item-* { padding: 0 10px; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div[class^="item-"]{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-1">1</div>
<div class="item-2">2</div>
<div class="item-3">3</div>
<div class="item-4">4</div>
```

Try with attribute selector

`div[class^="item-"]`